# Matrix element of $\exp(\vec v\cdot\vec J)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, representation-theory, rotation

$\vec J=(J_x,J_y,J_z)$ is angular momentum and $\vec v$ is a vector.

I want to know how to compute the matrix element of $\exp(\vec v\cdot\vec J)$, namely
$$
\langle jm\left|\exp(\vec v\cdot\vec J) \right|jm'\rangle
$$
where $\left| jm \right.\rangle$ is the eigenstate of $\hat J_z$.

Further more, I want to know
$$
\langle jm \left|\vec J\exp(\vec v\cdot\vec J) \right|jm'\rangle.
$$

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Have you tried using Taylor expansion and the commutation relations? Please show how you have approached this problem.